# binary universal turing machine code

Tags: computer-science, universal, turing-machines

In BINARY UNIVERSAL TURING MACHINE CODE how do we differentiate between the different turing machines..for example we can find the start and end of binary UTM code by '111' and we bifercate between two different states (q1,q2)with '11' but how do we differentiate the different turing machines that have been combined.

FOR example if we combine 3 turing machines to make a universal turing machine then our  binary universal turing machine code will look like 
1110000000001100000000000110000000000110000000011000000000110000000000011000000111
(well the code will be much larger)  so in this code how can we differentiate the three turing machines that have been included.